# MySQL Master Slave Replication where master is not allowed to talk to slave

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave-replication

I want to set up an Master Slave Replication between 2 different servers. The specialty is, that the Master is not allowed to talk to the slave, but the slave can talk with the master. I can not change slave to master, because the data inserted has to be on the master which can not talk (ping) with the slave. Can anyone tell me if I have to look at something when setting it up or can provide a guide which works good? Thanks in advance

Comment: to make sure I understand your question correctly, please correct me if I am wrong: you have two machine master and slave, master can not ping the slave, but slave can. and you want to sync the data from master to slave without changing network option.

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna you are right, only that i can't change the network option because of security reasons

Comment: Not that you need it at the moment, but I think "ssh forwarding" can provide the connection the other way.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for the tip, ill have a look at it once i need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that is required is for the slave to be able to establish and maintain a connection on the master's MySQL TCP port (3306 by default).  There is no need for the master to be able to establish a connection to the slave.  If you can telnet from the slave to port 3306 (or whatever port mysqld is running on) on the master, that should be all the networking you need.

There are a lot of guides, but the best one is the MySQL manual, see [Chapter 17 Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html).